# How to get query resultset into a string

Tags: java, string, resultset

In Java, after executing a query say I got a result set like:

```
bat 20 10
fat 20 5
cat 10 25
```

I want this resultset in a string such that the string will be:

```
bat,20,10 |fat,20,5 |cat,10,25
```

I am confused. How can I do that in Java?

Comment: How about a looping over result set and using StringBuilder to create string you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ResultSet rs = ...
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
while(rs.next()) {
 String s = rs.getString(1);
 int n1 = rs.getInt(2);
 int n2 = rs.getInt(3);
 b.append(s);
 b.append(",");
 b.append(n1);
 b.append(",");
 b.append(n2);
 b.append("|");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while iterating through the resultset you can append its contents to a string ..right.?

```
String finalStr = "";
while(resultSet.next()){
      finalStr+=resultSet.getString(1)+",";
      finalStr+=resultSet.getInt(2).toString()+",";
      finalStr+=resultSet.getInt(3).toString();
      finalStr+="|";
}
```

Comment: Using `String` here will have a great loss of performance, because the string objects will be copied every time you append the next part to it. Using `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` is recommended. I think it is not guaranteed that the compiler will optimize this to use `StringBuilder`..